# Create a package of OS image and Software

Tags: ubuntu

Suppose when we install ubuntu we get so many default application on it like firefox or media player etc.So can we see the source code of ubuntu and understand how these application are actually put into it so that they get installed along with the OS.I want to create a package of OS image and a set of softwares to be deployed on a VM

Comment: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in CentOS, RHEL, and Fedora you have something called anaconda, which installs out of a repo of rpm packages ( http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/BuildEnvironment )

With Ubuntu you have options like kickstart (https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html) or the roll your own live cd distro (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)

Kickstart is somewhat similar to Anaconda as well. It does not take much to add custom packages, or change whats installed by default. you can do more advanced things with %post install scripts as well.

Comment: hey thanks for that. i guess that should help. i am creating a web based desktop virtualization application. I wanted to give my users the flexibility to choose the OS they wanted to run and also the software they want along with their os, so that they may not have to install anything separately.Consider this situation if anyone can suggest anything about implementation.

Comment: very nice of @brian mains for this answer and edit. It helped me a lot. It saved me much pain.